# R group by, counting non-NA values

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe that has a scattering of NA's

```
toy_df
# Y  X1 X2 Label
# 5  3  3  A
# 3  NA 2  B
# 3  NA NA C
# 2  NA 6  B
```

I want to group this by the label field, and count how many non NA values are in each variable for each label.

```
desired output:
# Label Y  X1 X2
# A     1  1  1
# B     2  0  2
# C     1  0  0
```

I've done this using loops at the moment, but it's slow and untidy and I'm sure there's a better way.

Aggregate seems to get half way there, but it includes NA's in the count.

```
aggregate(toy_df, list(toy_df$label), FUN=length)
```

Any ideas appreciated...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(toy_df)`), grouped by 'Label', loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `sum` of non-NA values (`!is.na(x)`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(toy_df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), by = Label]
#   Label Y X1 X2
#1:     A 1  1  1
#2:     B 2  0  2
#3:     C 1  0  0
```

---

Or with `dplyr` using the same methodology

```
library(dplyr)
toy_df %>% 
      group_by(Label) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

---

Or a `base R` option with `by` and `colSums` grouped by the 4th column on logical matrix (`!is.na(toy_df[-4])`)

```
by(!is.na(toy_df[-4]), toy_df[4], FUN = colSums)
```

Or with `rowsum` with similar approach as in `by` except using the `rowsum` function.

```
rowsum(+(!is.na(toy_df[-4])), group=toy_df[,4])
#  Y X1 X2
#A 1  1  1
#B 2  0  2
#C 1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R

```
aggregate(toy_df[,1:3], by=list(toy_df$Label), FUN=function(x) { sum(!is.na(x))})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(cbind(toy_df$Y, toy_df$X1, toy_df$X2), list(toy_df$label),
          FUN = function (x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```