# Counting specific values of binary variable and returning the count only, preferably using dplyr

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I've got to get the frequency of one specific value of one single dichotomous variable, preferable using `dplyr` but I'll gladly accept alternative solutions. It should just be as short and straightforward as possible.

Here's the example:

```
dat<-data.frame(x=c(1,1,0,0,NA,NA))
```

What I could do is this...

```
dat %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(sum(!is.na(x)))
```

...based on what @akrun suggested in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150212/r-group-by-counting-non-na-values).

The issues with this is that it returns a tibble showing the count for each value `x` takes:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x `sum(!is.na(x))`
  <dbl>            <int>
1    0.                2
2    1.                2
3   NA                 0
```

What I need is just one number for a specific value of `x`, say `x==1`. Adding this condition (`x==1`) to the `dplyr` command, however, won't work, as it only returns the same tibble output as above.

Simply put, I need a command that returns the count of `x==1` **or** `x==2` and just that. So in this case, the perfect R output would look like this:

```
[1] 2
```

I've also tried something like this...

```
!is.na(dat[,c("x")]==1)
```

which returns an integer that equals `TRUE` if `x==1` and `FALSE` otherwise. But then I'd need to count the `TRUE`s.

Comment: Do you need something like `sum(dat$x == 1, na.rm = T)` for example?

Comment: [Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)

Comment: Lol, yes exactly. Somehow I assumed this wouldn't work because I tried `sum(!is.na(...)==1)` which just returns the full length of that variable (except for NAs) and ignores the `==1` command...

Comment: The problem with using `dplyr` for this is that it's made for working with data frames and you don't want a data frame result. So you could do something like `dat %>% summarize(sum(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% pull`, but it's simpler to skip `dplyr` altogether and just do what Antonios suggests: `sum(dat$x == 1)`. (Or maybe you want `sum(dat$x %in% c(1, 2), na.rm = TRUE)`? I can't really tell the specifics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using 'nrow'

```
dat %>% filter(x == 1) %>% nrow()
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same.