# Counting columns with NAs after group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to count the number of columns that have an NA value after using `group_by`.

Similar questions have been asking, but counting total NAs not columns with NA ([group by counting non NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150212/r-group-by-counting-non-na-values))

Data:

```
  Spes <- "Year Spec.1 Spec.2 Spec.3 Spec.4
    1      2016   5      NA     NA     5
    2      2016   1      NA     NA     6
    3      2016   6      NA     NA     4
    4      2018   NA     5      5      9
    5      2018   NA     4      7      3
    6      2018   NA     5      2      1
    7      2019   6      NA     NA     NA
    8      2019   4      NA     NA     NA
    9      2019   3      NA     NA     NA"

    Data <- read.table(text=spes, header = TRUE)
    Data$Year <- as.factor(Data$Year)
```

The desired output:

```
2016 2
2018 1
2019 3
```

I have tried a few things, this is my current best attempt. I would be keen for a `dplyr` solution.

```
> Data %>% 
   group_by(Year) %>% 
   summarise_each(colSums(is.na(Data, [2:5])))

Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
```

I have tried variations without much luck. Many thanks

Comment: `no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'logical')` will experiment with this though! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to `group_by` `Year`, check if there is `any` `NA` values  in each column and calculate their sum for each `Year`.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise_all(~any(is.na(.))) %>%
   mutate(output = rowSums(.[-1])) %>%
   select(Year, output)


# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Year  output
#  <fct>  <dbl>
#1 2016       2
#2 2018       1
#3 2019       3
```

---

Base R translation using `aggregate`

```
rowSums(aggregate(.~Year, Data, function(x) 
             any(is.na(x)), na.action = "na.pass")[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: Works! Many thanks, will answer as soon as allowed.

Comment: _I'm being cheeky_ but is there a line I could add to return column names? will edit question if there is a quickfix

Comment: @Jim which column names do you want to return ?

Comment: this with `NA` present, example output:  `2016  2  Spec.2,Spec.3` (I realise this is not correct protocol on SO, I will edit the question accordingly)

Comment: @Jim So something like `Data %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise_all(~any(is.na(.))) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Year) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  select(-value)` would help ?

Comment: Brilliant, I'll figure it out. Cheers!